# Copying NSDate objects and releasing

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate

if I do this:

```
NSDate *dateStart;
[dateStart alloc];

// Initialise with a date somewhere here..

..

// Modify the start date.
dateStart = [chosenDate copy];
```

Should I be doing a [dateStart release] before assigning the dateStart pointer?

I'm from a C/C++ background and I don't understand the whole ObjectiveC/iOS garbage collection behaviour (if indeed there is any). My C background is telling me I should be freeing the initial NSDate object that dateStart is pointing to. Would that be correct?

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understood your question, but if you use ARC, you don't need to release objects, it does it by itself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes since you allocated it before you should release it before this line

```
//Release it before reassign
[dateStart release];
dateStart = [chosenDate copy];
```

Also notice that its preferred that you do the allocation and initialization on the same line, dont break them to multiple lines

So this

```
NSDate *dateStart;
[dateStart alloc];
```

Would change to

```
NSDate *dateStart = [[dateStart alloc] init....];
```